# First entry from sql table not retrieved in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to fetch records from MySQL database in a java class, and the `first` entry isn't getting fetched.
Here is the class in which I'm trying to fetch the records :

```
public class BookDaoImpl
{
    private static String SELECT;

    static
    {
        SELECT = "SELECT * FROM databaseName.books;"; 
    }

    public BookDaoImpl()
    {
        connection = JDBCDaoImpl.getConnection();
    }

    public List<Book> fetchBooksList() throws SQLException
    {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SELECT);

        if (!resultSet.next())
            return null;

        List<Book> listOfBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
        Book tempBook;

        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            tempBook = new Book();

            tempBook.setBookId(resultSet.getInt("bookId"));
            tempBook.setBookName(resultSet.getString("bookName"));
            tempBook.setBookPrice(resultSet.getInt("bookPrice"));
            tempBook.setBookQuantity(resultSet.getInt("bookQuantity"));

            listOfBooks.add(tempBook);
        }

        System.out.println("listOfBooks : ");

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfBooks.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(listOfBooks.get(i));
        }

        return listOfBooks;
    }
}
```

Also, even if I add a few more entries to the table, the first entry still doesn't come.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You skip the first entry here:

```
if (!resultSet.next())
    return null;
```

If you delete these two rows of code, your method will work fine (but return an empty list instead of null, in the case no entries exist).

Comment: yeah, I just figured out the mistake and came here to delete the question! :P
Thanks anyways! :)